# I have an error within my code, probably syntax or with the if statements that I can't find. New to programming

Tags: c++, if-statement, syntax

So this is probably my first program ever basically. It takes user input about triangles then classifies them and outputs what kind of triangle the data given implies.I'm sorta guessing as I go along how things work just to play around with c++, but I've run into a problem. I'm not getting the intended results from my program (although they weren't perfect before) now instead of taking input for side lengths, I input the first side length and it automatically skips the other 2 side lengths and continues on with the code.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
int sideA, sideB, sideC, angleA, angleB, angleC, longest, middle, shortest, sumbc, sumac, sumab;
int main()
{
cout << "Enter an angle for angle A\n";
cin >> angleA;
cout << "Enter an angle for angle B\n";
cin >> angleB;
cout << "Enter an angle for angle C\n";
cin >> angleC;
sumbc = angleB+angleC;
sumac = angleA+angleC;
sumab = angleA+angleB;
if(angleA + angleB + angleC == 180){ // This confirms that the angles add to 180 to form a triangle
        cout << "This is a triangle!(Based on Angles)\n";

if(angleA == 90){ // These are for right angle triangles
        cout << "This is a real right triangle!(angleA is 90 degrees..)\n";
        cout << "Please enter the side lengths now\n";
        cout << "Side 1:\n";
        cin >> sideA;
        cout << "Side 2:\n";
        cin >> sideB;
        cout << "Side 3:\n";
        cin >> sideC;
        if(sideA > sideB && sideA > sideC){
            longest = sideA;
            cout << "Side 1 is the hypotenuse!\n";
        }
        else if(sideB > sideA && sideB > sideC) {
            cout << "Side 2 is the hypotenuse\n";
            longest = sideB;
        }
        else if(sideC > sideA && sideC > sideB){
            cout << "The hypotenuse is Side 3\n";
            longest = sideC;
        }
        if(longest == sideC && sideA == sideB) { //Determines what kind of triangle it is if the longest side is sideC
                cout << "This triangle is Right and Isosceles\n  ";

        }
        else if(longest == sideB && sideC == sideA){
                cout << "This triangle is Right and Isosceles\n  ";

        }
        else if(longest == sideA && sideB == sideC ){
            cout << "This triangle is Right and Isosceles\n  ";
        }
        else {
            cout << "This triangle is right and Scalene!\n";
        }


    }
if(angleB == 90){ // These are for right angle triangles

        cout << "This is a real right triangle!(angleB is 90 degrees..)\n";
        cout << "Please enter the side lengths now\n";
        cout << "Side 1:\n";
        cin >> sideA;
        cout << "Side 2:\n";
        cin >> sideB;
        cout << "Side 3:\n";
        cin >> sideC;
        if(sideA > sideB && sideA > sideC){ //Finds longest side
            longest = sideA;
            cout << "Side 1 is the hypotenuse!\n";
        }
        else if(sideB > sideA && sideB > sideC) {
            cout << "Side 2 is the hypotenuse\n";
            longest = sideB;
        }
        else if(sideC > sideA && sideC > sideB){
            cout << "The hypotenuse side is Side 3";
            longest = sideC;
        }
        if(longest == sideC && sideA == sideB) { //Determines what kind of triangle it is if the longest side is sideC
                cout << "This triangle is Right and Isosceles\n  ";

        }
        else if(longest == sideB && sideC == sideA){
                cout << "This triangle is Right and Isosceles\n  ";

        }
        else if(longest == sideA && sideB == sideC ){
            cout << "This triangle is Right and Isosceles\n  ";
        }
        else {
            cout << "This triangle is right and scalene!\n";
        }


    }
if(angleC == 90){ // These are for right angle triangles


        cout << "This is a real right triangle!(angleC is 90 degrees..)\n";
        cout << "Please enter the side lengths now\n";
        cout << "Side 1:\n";
        cin >> sideA;
        cout << "Side 2:\n";
        cin >> sideB;
        cout << "Side 3:\n";
        cin >> sideC;
        if(sideA > sideB && sideA > sideC){
            longest = sideA;
            cout << "Side 1 is the hypotenuse!\n";
        }
        else if(sideB > sideA && sideB > sideC) {
            cout << "Side 2 is the hypotenuse\n";
            longest = sideB;
        }
        else if(sideC > sideA && sideC > sideB){
            cout << "The hypotenuse is Side 3";
            longest = sideC;
        }
        if(longest == sideC && sideA == sideB) { //Determines what kind of triangle it is if the longest side is sideC
                cout << "This triangle is Right and Isosceles\n  ";

        }
        else if(longest == sideB && sideC == sideA){
                cout << "This triangle is Right and Isosceles\n  ";

        }
        else if(longest == sideA && sideB == sideC ){
            cout << "This triangle is Right and Isosceles\n  ";
        }
        else {
            cout << "This triangle is right and scalene!\n";
        }


    }
if(angleA == angleB && angleB == angleC){ // This is for equiangular/equilateral triangles

            cout << "This is an equiangular/equilateral triangle.\n ";
            cout << "Please enter the side lengths now\n";
            cout << "Side 1:\n";
            cin >> sideA;
            int periequal = sideA*3;
            int areaequal = sideA*sideA*.5;
            cout << "The area is : " << areaequal << std::endl << "The perimeter is: " << periequal << std::endl;
            cout << "This triangle is Isosceles, Equiangular, Equilateral, and Acute ";


            }

    if(angleA < 90 && sumbc != 120 && angleB < 90 && angleC < 90){ //deals with acute triangles
        cout << "This is an acute triangle!\n";
        cout << "Please enter the side lengths now\n";
        cout << "Side 1:\n";
        cin >> sideA;
        cout << "Side 2:\n";
        cin >> sideB;
        cout << "Side 3:\n";
        cin >> sideC;
        int AcuteIsoPeri = sideA + sideB + sideC;
            if (sideA == sideB){
                    cout << "This is an Acute, Isosceles Triangle. \n" << "With a perimeter of: " << AcuteIsoPeri;

            }
             else if(sideA == sideC){
                 cout << "This is an Acute, Isosceles Triangle. \n" << "With a perimeter of: " << AcuteIsoPeri;
            }
            else if(sideB == sideC){
                 cout << "This is an Acute, Isosceles Triangle. \n" << "With a perimeter of: " << AcuteIsoPeri;
            }
            else{
                cout << "This is an Acute, Scalene Triangle. \n" << "With a perimeter of " << AcuteIsoPeri;
            }

    } //end of angleA if statement
    if(angleA > 90){  //Deals with obtuse
    cout << "This angle is Obtuse, angle A is greater than 90..";
    cout << "Please enter the side lengths now\n";
        cout << "Side 1:\n";
        cin >> sideA;
        cout << "Side 2:\n";
        cin >> sideB;
        cout << "Side 3:\n";
        cin >> sideC;
            if (sideA == sideB){
                    cout << "This is an Obtuse, Isosceles Triangle. \n";

            }
            else if(sideA == sideC){
                 cout << "This is an Obtuse, Isosceles Triangle. \n";
            }
            else if(sideB == sideC){
                 cout << "This is an Obtuse, Isosceles Triangle. \n";
            }
            else{
                cout << "This is an Obtuse, Scalene Triangle. \n";
            }
}
        else if(angleB > 90){
    cout << "This angle is Obtuse, angle B is greater than 90..";
    cout << "Please enter the side lengths now\n";
        cout << "Side 1:\n";
        cin >> sideA;
        cout << "Side 2:\n";
        cin >> sideB;
        cout << "Side 3:\n";
        cin >> sideC;
                       if (sideA == sideB){
                    cout << "This is an Obtuse, Isosceles Triangle. \n";

            }
            else if(sideA == sideC){
                 cout << "This is an Obtuse, Isosceles Triangle. \n";
            }
            else if(sideB == sideC){
                 cout << "This is an Obtuse, Isosceles Triangle. \n";
            }
            else{
                cout << "This is an Obtuse, Scalene Triangle. \n";
            }
}
        else if(angleC > 90){
        cout << "This angle is Obtuse, angle C is greater than 90..";
        cout << "Please enter the side lengths now\n";
        cout << "Side 1:\n";
        cin >> sideA;
        cout << "Side 2:\n";
        cin >> sideB;
        cout << "Side 3:\n";
        cin >> sideC;
                    if (sideA == sideB){
                    cout << "This is an Obtuse, Isosceles Triangle. \n";

            }
        else if(sideA == sideC){
                 cout << "This is an Obtuse, Isosceles Triangle. \n";
            }
        else if(sideB == sideC){
                 cout << "This is an Obtuse, Isosceles Triangle. \n";
            }
        else{
                cout << "This is an Obtuse, Scalene Triangle. \n";
            }
}
        }




//scalene, obtuse, acute
return 0;
}
```

So I probably have no idea what I'm doing and I'm a terrible programmer or something haha, but here is what I get when I put in this information:
Info: Angles are 40,114,26 ..it idetifies that it is obtuse which is right, then it asks for the side lengths which is also what I intended for it to do.. Then I put in the first side length(6.4) and the program skips to the end once I press enter. I probably made a syntax error that I can't find, or the way I used if statements is plain wrong. If you can help with this mess that would be much appreciated! (Started researching c++ the other night and wanted to apply it to something real which is how this monster was created..)[Examle of Proper Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0Zgn.png)...
[Example of Wrong Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLipD.png)

Comment: you have a logic error. Program compiles and links fine. In case of syntax error the program won't compile

Comment: @Nandu Oh okay, thankyou I will update the question..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I cannot reproduce your error. When you write code, it is a good idea to start with something small and simple that works perfectly, then add complexity a little at a time, testing at every step. That way you don't wind up looking for a bug that could be anywhere in a huge program. If you *do* wind up there, try to *simplify* the code to a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the simplest example that produces the error. That will make the hunt much easier, for you and for us.

Comment: @Beta Well, it was simple at first.. When I started it a few hours ago it only identified equiangular triangles, but I tried to make it able to classify every type of triangle by angles and sides both. I think I will just scrap this and try again tomorrow with that suggestion in mind (minimal coding), when I coded this I was taking it a bit at a time, but I probably didnt test each bit of code as much as I should've.

Comment: @user3739597 See edits to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int sideA, sideB, sideC, angleA, angleB, angleC, longest, middle, shortest, sumbc, sumac, sumab;
```

All of your variables are of [type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) `int`. These only hold whole numbers. The type you probably want is `float` or `double`, which are floating point types that can hold real numbers:

```
double sideA, sideB, sideC, angleA, angleB, angleC, longest, middle, shortest, sumbc, sumac, sumab;
```

After you start using these types, you're going to have a problem with these lines:

```
if(angleA + angleB + angleC == 180)
if(angleA == 90)
```

The problem is that even if you enter values that might add up to 180 on paper, in a computer, 50.0+50.0+80.0 may equal 179.999992 or something like that. See [What every programmer should know about floating point math](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

Are you sure that one of these three if statements will always evaluate to `true`?

```
    if(sideA > sideB && sideA > sideC){
        longest = sideA;
        cout << "Side 1 is the hypotenuse!\n";
    }
    else if(sideB > sideA && sideB > sideC) {
        cout << "Side 2 is the hypotenuse\n";
        longest = sideB;
    }
    else if(sideC > sideA && sideC > sideB){
        cout << "The hypotenuse is Side 3\n";
        longest = sideC;
    }
```

If not, `longest` will not have ever had a value assigned and you'll get unexpected results.

There are other problems in your code, but I stopped looking at this point. Good luck.

Comment: longest only applied to right triangles. So does it need a value if it only applies if the triangle is a right triangle? and as I was working quickly and my knowledge is very limited I'm sure that very little of this program is correct or efficient .

Answer (score 0):

The short of the problem is that you are trying put put a float/double into an integer.  cin does not like it when you mix types like that.  The same thing would happen if you put in the letter 'a'.  Try using floats instead of ints.

EDIT : To clarify I mean make your sides and angles into floats.  The program worked for me so long as I didn't put in a number with a decimal point.

Comment: I hadn't learned about the "float" data type yet, and that solved the problem it seems. Is float what I should always use for low digit decimal numbers?

Comment: Depends on what you need.  Floats and doubles can, but don't always, have decimal places.  it depends on the size of the number.  I would highly recommend looking into this now because float rounding can cause you errors that will keep you searching for days.